# Magento 2: Import will not import more than 1 product at a time

Tags: product, import, import-products

Magento 2 version 2.2.6 will not import more than 1 product at a time.

The import will not create, update, or delete.

I've checked the import history, but there are no errors.  I've validated the files also and imported the CSV successfully.

However, it doesn't look like any data were written to the database.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $yourQty, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $yourQty, 'is_in_stock' => 1]);
```